# TextBox Keypress Event Validation

Tags: c#, event-handling, keypress

I would like to have a validation on my text box based the users input (keypress event). I have set the max length of my text box to 3 characters. The first character entered by the user should be a character (from a-z) and then the two succeeding characters must be a number. Backspace is allowed. So far I have this code but does not work as I would want to..

```
private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            countChar = this.textBox1.Text;
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(this.textBox1.Text))
            {
                e.Handled = !(char.IsLetter(e.KeyChar) || e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Back);
            }
            else if (countChar.Length == 1)
            {
                e.Handled = e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Back;
            }
            else if (countChar.Length == 2 || countChar.Length == 3)
            {
                e.Handled = e.KeyChar >= '0' && e.KeyChar <= '9' || e.KeyChar == (char)8;
            }
    }
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Would you mind elaborating on "does not work"? That doesn't really tell us very much. Compile error? Runtime exception? Unexpected behavior? If the behavior is unexpected, the best way to figure it out is to step through the code. We can't do that.

Comment: Also, it sounds like you mind want to try some regex to validate the contents of the textbox. Might be easier than trying to validate every single key press.

Comment: Oh sorry what I just meant to say is that it has some unexpected behavior. When I input the first character on the text box it accepts if it is a character but not a number. But when I input the second character on the text box it does not accept whether it is a character or a number. I've tried stepping through the code and still confused. Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: No problem, your english is quite good actually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
    private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        countChar = this.textBox1.Text;

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(this.textBox1.Text))
        {
            e.Handled = !(char.IsLetter(e.KeyChar) || e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Back);
        }
        else if (countChar.Length == 1 || countChar.Length == 2)
        {
            e.Handled = !(char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) || e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Back);
        }
        else if (countChar.Length == 3)
        {
            e.Handled = e.KeyChar != (char)Keys.Back;
        }
        else
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        countChar = this.textBox1.Text;
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(this.textBox1.Text))
        {
            e.Handled = (char.IsLetter(e.KeyChar);
        }
        else if (countChar.Length == 1 || countChar.Length == 2)
        {
            e.Handled = e.KeyChar >= '0' && e.KeyChar <= '9' || e.KeyChar == (char)8;
        }
       e.Handled=false;
   }
```

Comment: for first character textbox is empty yet. so in first if you can check it. for 2 next character your textbox lenght is 1 or 2. otherwise input character is incorrect

Comment: @user3233787 I've told you before on your question and it appears I need to tell you again. You are not elaborating enough on the problem for Mostafa to have a chance at fixing the code to work properly. If you refuse to go into more detail other than "it does not work", this is as much as you're going to get.